# Php newbie, difference of pdt from eclipse and zend?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Is there any difference downloading the **pdt** from *eclipse* install software/Programming languages/pdt versus the http://downloads.zend.com/pdt from the zend website?

I'm using [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en), how do I intigrate the **zend** framework in the projects?

I'm a total new in php so please dont assume anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never a guarantee that something on another host is the same. If you are in doubt always go with the authority which in this case would be Eclipse. Projects in Eclipse are just containers for your project in the IDE and it has nothing to do with the server.

Good luck with ZF as a php newbie!